# how to release a object which has a NStimer working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i don't want to write a code like "myview.timer invalidate" before [myview release].
but if the timer is working, i can't release myview, because timer retain myview.
how can i do?

i want to make the class"myview"  simple, just call [myview init] and [myview release]

***myview.h***

```
@interface MyView : UIView {
    NSString *str;
    NSTimer *timer;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSTimer *timer;
- (void)start;
- (void)doAction;
@end
```

***myview.m***

```
@implementation MyView
@synthesize str, timer;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
        NSString *_str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Timer is Running!!! Not Release"];
        self.str = _str;
        [_str release];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start {
    NSTimer *_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(doAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.timer = _timer;
}

- (void)doAction {
    NSLog(@"%@",self.str);
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [str release];
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

***contrllor.m***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    MyView *my_view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    self.myView = my_view;
    [my_view release];

    [myView start];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)releaseMyView {
    [myView removeFromSuperview];
    [myView release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repetitive timer retains its target. So if you use repetitive timer then you must invalidate it, and the place to invalidate must not be `dealloc`. `dealloc` won't be called unless you invalidate the timer. That's the way `NSTimer` is designed. As you have a `start` method, you can write a `stop` method which will invalidate the timer, if you are looking for more readable code. The logic is simple: you need to stop if you have started.

Another option is instead of `self` you can use a different object as the target of the timer. Then you can invalidate the timer in `dealloc`. But probably this is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Invalidate the timer.

When invalidated, it'll release the target.

Add to your view class:

```
-(void)stop
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}
```

And call it first thing from your `releaseMyView` method;  `[myView stop];`

Comment: i want to make the class"myview" sample, just call [myview init] and [myview release]

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like dispose method. 
Your controller code will looks like:

```
- (IBAction)releaseMyView {
    [myView removeFromSuperview];
    [myView dispose];
    [myView release];
}
```

And dispose method will invalidate the timer. This code will be very obvious, so you can perform other cleanup in dispose method.

Other way, you can check in doAction method if view still has superview. If not - invalidate timer.